# how to remove # from form action

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a login form using jquery mobile, php and mysql
this is the code

```
<form action="check_login.php" method="post"> 
  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="Username" />
  </div>
  <div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <input type="password" name="username" id="username" value="Password" />
  </div>
  <div class="ui-body ui-body-b">         
    <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
      <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit" data-theme="a">Login</button></div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</form>
```

But the problem is that, on submitting the form, it will be redirecting to index.php#check_login.php instead of loading /check_login.php to validate the login

How to do that?

Comment: There is a mistake..

<input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="Password" />

Comment: <script src= "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src= "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

You can set up following jQuery script:

```
$(document).submit(function() {
    $.post("/check_login.php", $("form").Serialize(), function(data) {
        // perform other actions depending on what exactly check_login.php does, and returns
    });
});
```

You just invoke the HTTP POST method to the url of your desire, but you need to handle the response on your own...

Comment: could you please explain this code and tell me where to modify the current code?